# Saving user content in RShiny as specified named variables

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm trying to build a simple data entry sheet for media data which a user can add data too and save in a desired location. At the moment whenever I save a scenario it saves the variable as data, which i assume is due to the argument in the save function. I would like the variable to be saved as the input$name value but i can't for the life of me figure out how. I've tried using assign etc. but to no avail. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    library(shiny)
    library(rhandsontable)
    library(data.table)

    setwd(choose.dir())

    saveData <- function(data,name) {
    # Create a unique file name
    # Write the file to the local system
    save(
    x = data,
    file =  paste0(name,".rdata")
    )
    }

    ui <- fluidPage(
     rHandsontableOutput('table'),
     textInput("savename",label = "File Name"),
     actionButton("save",label = "save")
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
      #build table via user controls
      start.date <- as.Date("2017/1/1")
      end.date <- as.Date("2017/1/5")
      date.range <- as.character(seq(start.date,end.date,by='day'))
      Channels <- c("TV","OOH","AFFILIATES","DIGITAL")
      df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,length(Channels),length(date.range),dimnames = list(Channels,date.range)))
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df, height = 220,width = 1500, colWidths = 200,rowHeights = 40, rowHeaderWidth  = 200, colHeaderHeight = 30, className =  "htCenter htMiddle")})

  #data input
  data1 <- eventReactive(input$save, {
    df <- hot_to_r(input$table)
    df <- t(df)
    df <- as.data.frame(df)
    df <- setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
    colnames(df)[1] <- "Date"
    df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
    df
    })

  observeEvent(input$save, {
    name <- input$savename
    saveData(data1(),name)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assign()` then call `save(list= )`:

```
saveData <- function(data,name) {
  assign(name, data)
  save(
    list = name,
    file = paste0(name, ".rdata")
  )
}
```